# Haskell Function that calculates e^x

Tags: haskell, recursion, taylor-series

Implement a function that calculates the value of e ^ x, x is a parameter of the function, an integer.
To do this, use the Taylor series expansion to calculate the potency of e.
The function will receives as a parameter, in addition to the exponent x, the number of terms of the series, which will operate as a maximum value of n.
For the resolution of this function, recursion must be used.

I made this:

```hs
factorial 0 = 1
factorial n = n * factorial (n-1)

consigna3::Int->Int->Float
consigna3 _ 0 = 1
consigna3 x n = (fromIntegral(x^n) / fromIntegral(factorial n)) + consigna3 x (n-1)
```

But some results are wrong, this is what I expected:

```
Ejemplo 1: Main> funcion3 1 1
           2.0
Ejemplo 2: Main> funcion3 1 10
           2.718282
Ejemplo 3: Main> funcion3 2 10
           7.388997
Ejemplo 4: Main> funcion3 10 20
           21991.48
Ejemplo 5: Main> funcion3 10 30
           22026.46
Ejemplo 6: Main> funcion3 0 30
           1.0
```

The results (10 20) and (10 30) do not match what the function I did returns.
What I am doing wrong? Thanks and sorry for my English.

Comment: Do you have expected results for `funcion3` involving `10` and smaller values for `n`? I suspect `funcion3` was implemented in a way that is affected less by floating-point rounding error.

Comment: `factorial 30` is much larger than the maximum `Int` value.  You should be using `Integer` for calculations like these.  Also I would suggest `Double` instead of `Float` -- you need all the precision you can get the way you are doing it.

Comment: this should really be calculated in `Rational`s. use the code in the accepted answer but replace `/` with `%`. convert only the final result to a floating point number, with `fromRational`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using `Int` for calculations that will overflow an `Int`. Instead, convert to `Float` right away, and then using `Float` for everything. So:

```
consigna3 x n = ((fromIntegral x)^n / factorial (fromIntegral n)) + consigna3 x (n-1)
```

There are two critical changes from `Int` to `Float` here: first, you do `x^n` where `x :: Int`, but I do `fromIntegral x^n` where `fromIntegral x :: Float`; second, you do `factorial n` where `n :: Int`, but I do `factorial (fromIntegral n)` where `fromIntegral n :: Float`.